# Error: Format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB specification

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting an error

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB specification.

and this code stop on `.open` line.

How can I fix this problem?

```
Public Const sDEMAND_ROLE_GUID As String = "{6AA0B273-2548-49ED-9592-78243D4353AC}"

Public Const sSHAREPOINT_SITE As String ="https://eu001sp.domain.com/sites/"
Sub TestPullFromSharepoint()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConn As String
Dim sSQL As String
Dim ID As String

sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DATABASE=" & sSHAREPOINT_SITE & ";" & _
"LIST=" & sDEMAND_ROLE_GUID & ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With cn
    .ConnectionString = sConn
    .Open
End With
sSQL = "SELECT tbl.[name] FROM [Library Name] as tbl where tbl.[id] = 14"
rs.Open sSQL, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

End Sub
```

Comment: What does the OLE DB specification say about the format of initialization strings?

Comment: actullay that is the exact error that i got.

Comment: There's a dedicated website for connection strings https://www.connectionstrings.com/